Delete empty line when replacing text with nothing
I run a text replacement based on the value of the cell. The text replcement works fine but it always leaves the empty Google Doc line no matter what I try. I'd like to hit the delete or backspace button if the text is replaced so the text below the new empty space in my Google Doc where the data outputs moves up one line.
if(Data < 4){
      //Logger.log("Data < 4")
      p_new = p_new
      .copy()
      .replaceText("Text Text Text","")}

I've tried placing "\b" in the replcement text, but that doesn't work.

You may need to get the parent paragraph and remove it from  the body

Welcome to stackoverflow! Can you provide your full code and your desired output by editing the question above?

Please provide [mcve]

To avoid leaving an empty line, instead of using DocumentApp.Body.replaceText use DocumentApp.Body.findText, then delete the parent paragraph.
function myFunction() {
  const body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  body.findText( /** put here the string to find */ )
     .getElement()
     .getParent()
     .removeFromParent()
}

The concept is that you have to remove a paragraph having certain text. To make this more robust you might want, before removing the paragraph, to verify that the paragraph text lenght is the same as the text to find lenght.
